# Variable with high number of categories

Tags: r, anova, lm, many-categories

I would like some help with my analysis. I have an outcome variable that represents average number of errors somebody experiences per hour. It has about 26% zeros. 85% of values are smaller than 1. There are some outliers going up to >700.

My explanatory variables are only categorical variables. One has 3 categories, one has 2 categories, one has six categories and one has 91 categories (area within a country).

My question is whether anyone has some tips analyzing this dataset. I want to know the effects of the variables and potential interaction effects on the outcome. 
I would like to know as well if there are some locations that experience significantly high numbers of errors. 
Can anybody help me going in the right direction? I am just starting in statistics.

Comment: I'd reconsider your title. Is having one variable with a high number of categories central to your question?

Comment: I would like to include it in the analysis, but the other variables are important too. I don't know how to handle the variable with such a high number of categories

Comment: I wouldn't use the average number of errors per hour as my outcome variable if I could avoid it. Do you have information on the actual number of errors, & the number of hours for each person?

Comment: Yes, I have information about the actual number of errors. Per person, in which hour he watched television, how long he watched and how many errors he experienced.

Comment: For the variable with 91 categories, look into fused lasso. Search this site.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two issues here:

1) The distribution of the dependent variable and
2) The number of categories in one of the independent variables

Regarding 1) Since the variable is the *average* number of errors, it is essentially continuous, albeit very skewed. OLS regression makes no assumptions about the shape of the dependent variable, only about the residuals. But it is likely that they will be non-normal and you may need to transform the DV.

Regarding 2) There is no special reason you cannot have a variable with so many categories, provided that you have enough data. You will want to have enough cases in every region. You may need to combine regions.

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest the following:**

1) Inspect the assumption of a Poisson variable

2) Inspect overdispersion

3) Inspect excessive zeros

**If 1) is not rejected, then proceed with Poisson regression in a generalized linear model.**

**If 1) is rejected then**

If 2) is true and 3) is not, then proceed with Negative Binomial model.

If 2) is false and 3) is true, then proceed with Zero-Inflated Poisson model.

If both 2) and 3) are true, then proceed with Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial model.

Comment: I think you need extra cautions given that the response is measured, not counted. That doesn't rule out these kinds of models, but at least some of the software available may expect integers only. (@Peter Flom's answer is pertinent too.)

Comment: The dependent variable is not a count, so why use such a model? Or are you suggesting that the dependent variable be changed?

Comment: @PeterFlom "Average number of errors" looks like a count - or the average of several counts, that is just the rescaled count in a longer period. Can't it be seen as a Poisson variable? Counting of errors is a usual elementary textbook example of a Poisson process.

Comment: @page An average is not a count.  A count is a non-negative integer.  Averages can be fractional.